# Laravel resources - how to check if given value exists?

Tags: laravel

I'm using laravel resources to get data for api:

```
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'unread' => $this->unread,
            'contact' => UserResource::collection($this->users),
        ];
```

And this is working fine. The problem is when 'users' is empty. I mean - not every time my controller is loading users from my relations:

```
    $offers = Offer::where('user_id', $user_id)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
    foreach ($offers as $offer)
    {
        $offer->setRelation('users', $offer->users->unique());
    }
    return OfferShortResource::collection($offers);
```

sometimes - this relation does not exists. But not the relation is problem, because - my resource is not loading the relation - the relatin is loaded inside controller.

So how can I add some kind of logic to resources? - to tell basically - users property may not exists - then do not load data here, or even - do not check `$this->users` relation

edit: I tried to make it like this:

```
 use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
 ...

      'contact' => $this->when(Arr::exists($this, 'users'), function () {
                    return UserResource::collection($this->users);
                }),
```

but this is giving always false

edit 2: relation in the Offer model

```
 public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'messages', 'offer_id', 'from')
       ->where('users.id', '!=', auth()->user()->id);
```

Comment: Laravel Docs - Eloquent - API Resources - Conditional Relationships   `whenLoaded`

Comment: I tried this, giving error: `"message": "Class 'App\\Post' not found",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError",
    "file": "C:\\www2\\medpraca2\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Concerns\\HasRelationships.php",`

Comment: lol, no, my code is like: `'contact' => UserResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('users')),`

Comment: then that error obviously has nothing to do with what you have shown here, so not sure what you want anyone to do for you

Comment: trust me, when I comment this line there is no error, and my relation is working well inside controller

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using `whereHas`:

```
Offer::whereHas('users', function ($query) use ($user_id) {
    $query->where('user_id', $user_id);
})->orderByDesc('created_at')->get();
```

The [optional](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-optional) helper is useful for accessing properties that may not be defined:

```
optional($this->user)->name
```

The `when` method should work for you, try the following:

```
'contact' => $this->when(property_exists($this, 'users'), function () {
    return UserResource::collection($this->users);
}),
```

Also try:

```
isset($this->users)
```

Comment: It is a logic for controller, in controller everything works fine, I want to add logic to api Resource to conditionally add `'contact'` value

Comment: checking again for today and `property_exists($this, 'users')` isn't working inside resources, gives me always false, even if I would put it other value like  `property_exists($this, 'unread')` etc

Comment: Can you include the full code for `OfferShortResource`?

Comment: no, but I've tried now `isset($this->users)` and it works with it, you may update the answer and I'll accept again

Comment: anyway it's strange that `property_exists` is not working inside api resources

Comment: As reference for future visitors of this page, please have a look at the docs to solve this issue: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources#conditional-attributes

Comment: ```optional($this->user)->name``` i just loved it, this is what i needed.